# HornetQ MDB timeout

Tags: transactions, jms, jboss5.x, rollback

JBoss 5.1 with HornetQ

I need a MDB to rollback if it cannot process a message in 30 seconds. Is this possible ?

The `@TransactionTimeout(30000)` annotation doesn't seem to work.

I use it along with:

`@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)`
`@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)`

Current behavior is that if 5 minutes pass, JMS rolls back the transaction. However, this way the code is executed multiple times: for the first delivery and for each redelivery as JMS does know that the transactions has been canceled.

Could this be coped somehow ?
Ideally I would like the MDB to rollback before JMS cancels the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transactionTimeout", propertyValue = "30")
```